# Fonts look different on Firefox and IE than on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I am using three fonts that I load via `@font-face` and they all look like they are supposed to on Chrome, but on Firefox and IE they look different. Like with extra bold added to them and they are more blocky.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

How I apply these fonts to elements:

```
...
font-family: "OpenSans-Regular", sans-serif;
...
```

[image]

If I edit the element in Firefox with dev tools and set `font-family: Open Sans` then it works like it should.

This problem is giving me a headache as I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: On a CSS note, don't put the font style, weight, etc, in your font family name. These are `OpenSans`, `Montserrat`, and `Roboto`, tied *explicitly* to font-style "regular" and font-weight "normal", and as such you control whether these fonts kick in through those three values. You use `@font-face` to declare a *family*, and CSS then resolves that family to individual resources based on additional properties. It's why you can have 20 different rules all for the same family name but with different weight/style/etc. combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question was having different font weights, e.g. if you have google fonts then make sure you have light(300), regular (400), medium (500), bold (700) versions imported.

Answer (score 0):

All applications are developed with specific blocks of code. This is like "Default Font" on HTML and CSS. It happens with all web pages that are opened on different browsers. Try this thing with 
[Facebook](http://facebook.com) 
and you will see the difference between fonts on Chrome and Firefox. If font looked bolder than you wanted it, just play with "font-weight" on CSS StyleSheet. e.g.:

> body.font-weight: xx px;

Comment: I forgot to add the example image. It's not just "bolder". It doesn't have the round edges and it just looks fat with sharp edges. You can't really tell by the screenshot, because it's low quality, but it does look like a completely different font.

Comment: This is a web browser problem. Once I had a project on web developing, and my client had a MacBook PRO, and website looked completely different on Safari. As far as I know, this might be a browser problem

Answer (score 0):

late reply but here goes; Firefox renders headers and some other elements as "double bold" in your case so you would have to remove the font weight from the element in order to normalize this if you don't want to load more font files[1].

To improve the rendering, try loading the fonts as follows[2][3]:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('../fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('../fonts/roboto-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/roboto-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('../fonts/roboto-italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/roboto-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[1] It is better to have fewer fonts but include the correct ones

[2] just the Roboto as an example but the same would apply for the rest as well

[3] consider defining the values in absolute numbers rather than relative values as these can be interpreted differently by the different browsers